# HOC to add prop if it's a certain type

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to write a HOC that adds a `prop` if it's a certain type. I am iterating through it depth first. But when I try to set prop it says it's not extensible, I am trying to add prop of `value` to `HEEHAW`:

```
function fieldLayoutHOC(WrappedComponent: ComponentType) {
    return (
        class FieldLayoutWrap extends WrappedComponent {
            static displayName = wrapDisplayName(WrappedComponent, 'FieldLayoutWrap')

            render() {
                const view = super.render()
                // depth first - stack - last in first out
                // iterate depth first until a Field is found
                const elements = [view]; // stack

                console.log('view:', view);

                while (elements.length) {
                    const element = elements.pop();
                    const primative = typeof element;
                    if (primative === 'object') {
                        if (element.type === Field) {
                            // fields.push(element);
                            element.props.value = 'HEEHAW'; /////// not extensible error here
                            console.log('added value HEEHAWW');
                        } else {
                            if (element.props) {
                                const children = element.props.children;
                                if (children) {
                                    if (Array.isArray(children)) {
                                        elements.push(...children);
                                    } else {
                                        elements.push(children);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return view;
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: There may be a way to get this to work, but certainly React documentation recommends using [composition instead of inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). Instead of extending an existing class, you may be able to get what you want by composing one inside the other. The outer component can have some logic to change the props passed into the child.

Answer (score 1):

Well I came up with my own solution. I'm not mutating the props, which added the complication of holding on to a mutable version of the tree. This can definitely use some cleaning.

```
function addPropsIfHOCFactory(predicate) { //
  return function addPropsIfHOC(WrappedComponent) { // factory
    return (
      class FieldLayoutWrap extends WrappedComponent {

        render() {
          const view = super.render();
          if (!this.addProps) return view;

          // depth first - stack - last in first out
          // iterate depth first until a Field is found
          const viewElementNew = { node: view, parentElement: null };
          const tree = [viewElementNew]; // stack // parentElement is ref to parentElement in elements

          const elementsByDepth = {}; // key is depth, value is array of element's at that depth
          const elementsByParentId = {}; // key is elementId of parent
          let elementId = 0;
          // console.log('view:', view);

          let depthMax = 0;

          while (tree.length) {
            const element = tree.pop();

            element.props = element.node.props ? element.node.props : undefined;
            element.childrenElements = undefined;
            element.clone = undefined;
            element.depth = getDepth(element);
            element.id = elementId++;
            element.needsClone = false; // if true then clone, its set to true if props are changed

            if (element.depth > depthMax) depthMax = element.depth;

            if (!elementsByDepth[element.depth]) {
              elementsByDepth[element.depth] = [];
            }
            elementsByDepth[element.depth].push(element);

            const node = element.node;
            const primative = typeof node;
            if (primative === 'object' && node) {
              if (predicate(node)) {
                const addProps = isFunction(this.addProps) ? this.addProps(node) : this.addProps;
                element.props = Object.assign({}, node.props ? node.props : undefined, addProps);
                markBranchNeedsClone(element);
                console.log('added props to node:', element.node);
              }
            }

            if (node.props && node.props.children) {
              const children = node.props.children;

              const pushChild = child => {
                const parent = element;
                const childElement = {
                  node: child,
                  parentElement: parent
                }
                tree.push(childElement);
                if (!elementsByParentId[parent.id]) elementsByParentId[parent.id] = [];
                elementsByParentId[parent.id].push(childElement);

                return childElement;
              }

              if (Array.isArray(children)) {
                element.childrenElements = children.map(pushChild);
              } else {
                const child = children;
                element.childrenElements = pushChild(child);
              }
            }
          }

          // do React.cloneElement from deepest first IF needsClone === true
          let depth = depthMax + 1;
          while (depth--) {
            // console.log('doing now elementsByDepth[depth] of depth:', depth);
            for (const element of elementsByDepth[depth]) {
              if (typeof element.node === 'object' && element.node) {
                if (!element.needsClone) {
                  element.clone = element.node;
                } else {
                  let childrenClones = elementsByParentId[element.id];
                  if (childrenClones) {
                    if (childrenClones.length === 1) {
                      childrenClones = childrenClones[0].clone;
                    } else {
                      childrenClones = childrenClones.map(element => element.clone);
                    }
                  }
                  console.log('CLONING');
                  element.clone = React.cloneElement(element.node, element.props, childrenClones);
                }
              } else {
                // its a string, number etc
                element.clone = element.node;
              }
            }
          }

          // console.log('viewElementNew:', viewElementNew);
          // console.log('elementsByDepth:', elementsByDepth);
          // console.log('elementsByParentId:', elementsByParentId);

          return viewElementNew.clone;
        }
      }
    )
  }
}

function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
  var getType = {};
  return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
function getDepth(element) {
  let depth = 0;
  let elementCur = element;
  while (elementCur.parentElement) {
    elementCur = elementCur.parentElement;
    depth++;
  }
  return depth;
}
function markBranchNeedsClone(element) {
  let elementCur = element;
  while (elementCur) {
    elementCur.needsClone = true;
    elementCur = elementCur.parentElement;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import addPropsIfHOC from 'add-props-if'

// MY FORM COMPONENT
class BlahDumb extends React.Component {
  addProps = {
    placeholder: 'INJECTED PLACEHOLDER'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="url">URL</label>
        <div>
          <input id="url" type="text" />
          yeppers
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="foo" type="text" />
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const BlahPropsAdded = addPropsIfHOC(node => node.type === 'input')


const Blah = BlahPropsAdded(BlahDumb);



// MY APP COMPONENT
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
          <div className="app">
            <Blah />
          </div>
    )
  }
}

// RENDER
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Here it is working - https://codesandbox.io/s/6y1lrn7yww

Here is a demo which adds props to `<Field>` children: https://codesandbox.io/s/9zp9207nvy